# Module not found error can't resolve module in Azure Pipeline build

Tags: angular

Below is the `interceptormodule` this module is present in intercept library

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    interceptorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    MsalAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
    MsalInterceptorService
  ],
  exports: [
    interceptorComponent
  ]
})
export class interceptorModule { }
```

Imported above module in home project module

```
import { interceptorModule } from 'interceptor'; 
//this auto added by vscode as I used module below 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ],
imports: [ interceptormodule ],
providers: [Msalservice]
```

In local system it worked fine but after running azure pipeline getting build error cannot find interceptor module.

I tried using direct path in import

```
import {interceptormodule} from '../intercept/interceptormodule'
```

build is getting succeded but that service is not working.

Comment: is the path `'interceptor'` correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct. It's working in my local setup

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that you have a typo in the imports array of the home projects module. Also, try to rename `provider` to `providers`.

Try following in the home project module:

````
import { interceptorModule } from 'interceptor';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ],
imports: [ interceptorModule ], // and not interceptormodule 
provider: [Msalservice]
```
````

Comment: While drafting the question I made that mistake sorry about that edited question please check it